# Using a variable's value at function declaration time rather than run time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

This should be quite a simple problem, I've come across it enough that there should be an obvious solution, but I think I'm struggling to phrase it right.

I'm running a loop in JS/jQuery that binds functions to events for certain elements. As the elements are dynamically added to the page, I want the function to contain a reference to the specific element it will be modifying. A simplified example is shown below, along with the workaround code I'm using.

```
for (row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++) {
    $('#row' + row + ' input').keyup(function () {
        alert($(this).parent().parent().get(0).id);    
    });
}
```

The issue here is that in order to get a reference to the row, rather than using the variable being used in the loop, I have to pull the reference out of the row's ID in a long winded fashion (in the code above, there's then be another line that strips "row" from the identifier, omitted for clarity.)

What I'd like to work is something similar to:

```
for (row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++) {
    $('#row' + row + ' input').keyup(function () {
        alert(row);
    });
}
```

However, this obviously only returns the ID of the last element to be added. I'm sure there's a simple way of just taking the value of the variable rather than a reference to it, but I just haven't come across it yet. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should ***always*** use `var` for your loop variable, i.e. `for (var row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++)`

Comment: @Thief *Always*? I can think of a few examples where it would be useful to use a var that has been used elsewhere as the loop variable.

Comment: Well, at least unless it has been declared in the outer scope. What I wanted to say is that you should **never make your loop variable global**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (var row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++) {
    (function(row) {
        $('#row' + row + ' input').keyup(function() {
            alert(row);
        });
    })(row);
}
```

This creates a new closure and since the row is passed as a function argument it's "detached" from the loop variable.

Comment: This seems perfect, it's exactly the sort of simple solution I was expecting there to be, thanks!